# What is the time unit for ForegroundLockTimeout registry value in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

What is the time unit for ForegroundLockTimeout registry value in Windows 7?
Is this milliseconds, hours, seconds, nanoseconds or what? I can't figure out in the documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in milliseconds, according to the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957208.aspx).